# Como pegar uma Função Apartir de uma string

Tags: c#

Eu gostaria de fazer uma sistema que quando informado um número inteiro (Int) ele executasse uma determinada função.

Entrada Int > Função AcharObjeto > Transform int em um nome > executa a função com esse nome.

Exemplo: **Não e um CODIGO FUNCIONAL**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void AcharObjeto(int id)
    {
        for (int Type = 0; Type < Objects.ObjectsList.Length; Type++)
            if (id == Convert.ToInt32(Objects.ObjectsList[Type,1]))
               // Daqui para baixo não funciona e essa e a pergunta!!
               foreach(Obj in Objects)
               {
                   if(Obj.toString() == Objects.ObjectsList[Type,0])
                      Obj();
               }
    }
}

public class Objects
{
   public static string[,] ObjectsList = new string[1, 2] {
        { "Toalha", "1" }
   };

   public static void Toalha()
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("Toalha");
   }
}
```

Não sei si deu para entender mas gostaria de saber como fazer isso!
Eu fiz esse codigo em tema mercado tipo o cara vai lá e lê o código, aí ele tem que achar em uma lista de codigos e assimilar com a função que faz marcar o preço ou coisa assim.

**Um jeito mais facil de Entender:**

```
string namefunc = "teste";
Main.namefunc();
```

**RESPOSTAS EM C#, POR FAVOR**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso. A mais comum é fazer um invoke do método desejado, pegando-o via reflection.

Conforme exemplo apresentado, onde se conhece a classe em que se encontra o método, pode ser feito algo como:

```
var funcao = TypeDaclasseOndeEstaOMetodo.GetMethod("NomeDoMetodo");
funcao.Invoke(this, null);
```

Para isso é necessário fazer `using System.Reflection;`.

Para pegar o tipo da classe, o `TypeDaclasseOndeEstaOMetodo`, vc pode fazer algo como `var TypeDaclasseOndeEstaOMetodo = this.GetType();`, assumindo que ambos os métodos e onde há o invoke estão na mesma classe.

Esses detalhes podem variar de acordo com a sua implementação e organização do projeto. Faltam maiores informações na pergunta para apresentar algo mais detalhado.

---

Edit: Conforme código apresentado pelo AP.
Repl: https://repl.it/repls/ImpureBurdensomeDatasets

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    AcharObjeto(1);
  }

  public static void AcharObjeto(int id)
  {
    for (int Type = 0; Type < Objects.ObjectsList.GetLength(0); Type++)
    {
      if (id == Convert.ToInt32(Objects.ObjectsList[Type, 1]))
      {
        var ObjectsType = typeof(Objects);
        var funcao = ObjectsType.GetMethod(Objects.ObjectsList[Type,0]);
        funcao.Invoke(null, null);

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

public static class Objects
{
   public static string[,] ObjectsList = new string[1, 2] {
        { "Toalha", "1" }
   };

   public static void Toalha()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Toalha");
   }
}
```

Comment: o codigo de demonstração faz bem entender como gostaria de fazer. Não sei explicar mas vou tentar. 

eu quero chamar o codigo AcharObjecto() passando o id da toalha.
com isso quero chamar a func que ta na class Objectcs.Toalha().

quero fazer isso q o codido de demostração explica exatamento oq quero fazer.

não sei explicar melhor.

========= si possivel explique melhor a parte do TypeDaclasseOndeEstaOMetodo pois eu so tenho uma class e não posso usar this pois o codigo e static

Comment: @Zehous, neste caso vc pode fazer `typeof(SuaClasse)`.

Comment: @Zehous adicionei a lógica ao seu código.

Comment: ps: note também que está fazendo uso incorreto do array .Length. Fiz a correção na demonstração.

Comment: ***Obg Tambem Funcionou.***

Comment: @Zehous neste caso pode aceitar a resposta e dar o voto positivo

Comment: sim acabei de fazer isso. ps: (descobri agora que existia isso)

Comment: Como posso passar int como parametro pq funcao.Invoke(null, 0); não funciona

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_MethodBase_Invoke_System_Object_System_Object___), a 2a propriedade do `Invoke` é um array de objetos. Sendo assim, é necessário fazer `funcao.Invoke(null, new object[]{ 0 });`

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo que escreveste estás a tentar invocar directamente o objecto quando na realidade querias chamar uma função do mesmo.
O exemplo seguinte cria um objecto através do Activator.CreateInstance e depois invoca um método com o nome que lhe passas.
Usei o método exemplo que forneceste:

```
   public static void AcharObjeto(int id)
{
  for (int Type = 0; Type < Objects.ObjectsList.Length-1; Type++)
    if (id == Convert.ToInt32(Objects.ObjectsList[Type, 1]))
      foreach (var Obj in Objects.ObjectsList)
      {
        if (Obj.ToString() == Objects.ObjectsList[Type, 0])
        {
          var objType = typeof(Objects);
          var funcao = objType.GetMethod(Obj);
          object objectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(objType, new object[] { });
          funcao.Invoke(objectInstance, null);
        }
      }
}
```

Corri e funciona bem.

```
   public static void Main() {
    AcharObjeto(1);
   }
```

Comment: ***Obg Sim funcionou aqui tambem***. mas gostaria de entender melhor como funciona o Activator.CreateInstance. poderia ajudar a entender melhor esse commando??

Comment: Deixei como solução o 1° codigo. é que ele lá tinha resolvido mas n eu n tinha entendido.

Comment: é apenas uma maneira mais genérica de criar uma instância do objecto que contem o método a ser chamado. Para simplificar no teu exemplo podes substituir por:  funcao.Invoke(new Objects(), null);

Comment: obg por tentar ajudar mas já resolvi. obg pela atenção.